# Intersecting with then without a buffer in ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arcgis-pro, select-by-location

I'm pretty new to ModelBuilder and trying to create a model in which I take a point layer and intersect it with a polygon layer.

Basically, I need the model to first run an intersect with no Search Radius, then run it again with a search radius of 100 m, but only include points that haven't already been picked up in the first intersect run. I've tried using an 'If Field Value Is' function (where Join_Count=0) but no luck.

Comment: Do you really mean "intersect" as an intersection of a point against polygon is a point. Or are you asking about SELECTING based upon an _intersection_ relationship?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add Select by Location to your model twice (see below), you should be able to achieve what you want. First, run Select by Location, using your points as the Input Features (cities in my example) and your polygon layer as the Selecting Features (IL state boundary in my example). Set a search distance of 100 m (I used a 100 km just because of the scale of my layers) and Selection Type as New Selection (see screenshot below). Then use the output of that tool as the Input Features for your second Select by Location in Modelbuilder. Set the Relationship as Intersect with no search radius, and Selection Type as Remove from the current selection (see screenshot).

Now you should be left with the points that fall within 100 m of your boundary, but none of the ones that fall within it (see last screenshot).

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks - with a bit more poking I managed to get it to do what I wanted! Appreciate your help.

Comment: Right on, @rjls19191. Glad that worked for you.